# Using custom file for Android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to choose a custom location for the sqlite database file?

If possible I want to store the database file in the memory card. And if user switches from one memory card to the other I want my application to use whatever version of the database file available on the card.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default your database is stored in **data/data/your_package/databases**

You can use [**`SQLiteDatabase`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) [**`openOrCreateDatabase`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) where you can supply the path to your custom database as your first argument.

Comment: Android data storage documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) mentions that all databases are stored in a predefined folder. But API documentation for openOrCreateDatabase does not put any restrictions on file name. I think documentation is really confusing but this might be the solution.

Comment: yeah the documentation is heavily lacking, although this answers what you need, I think you are better off using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create the database and then copy the database file onto your memory card.

Answer (score 9):

You can access a database stored on you sdcard by using:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MyClass {
    private SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

    // Constructor
    public MyClass() {
        try {
            myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(stPathToDB, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS|SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    public void finalize() {
        myDB.close();
    }
}
```

NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS = to open the database without support for localized collators.

In order to get the path to your sdcard you can use:

```
stPathToDB = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/dbase.sqlite"
```

Rgds
Layne